# What events cause GCM re-registration?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app with a large user base that uses GCM.  A server side misconfiguration resulted in zero backups for our GCM registration DB (really bad!), now there is no way to message these apps.

My question is:  what client or server system events would cause GCM to re-register with the server?  e.g. client apk version update, client google play services update, etc.

As an alternative, is there a way for the server to basically invalidate ALL the token registrations such that all of the Android clients would be forced to re-register?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to release a new version of your app which (if your current logic doesn't already do it) should register to GCM and send the registration ID to your server. This, unfortunately, will give you the Registration IDs for only the devices that install the new version, but there's nothing better you can do.

You can add logic to your new app version that would be able to overcome this problem the next time it happens, this time without requiring a new version. For example, each time the app is launched, make an API call to your server that contains some unique ID of the app instance (not necessarily the Registration ID), and if your server doesn't find that ID in your DB (or doesn't find a Registration ID associated with it), you force the app instance to go through some registration process, that would require the app to re-send the Registration ID to your server. This still won't help you restore the Registration IDs of devices that don't launch your app, but at least you'll be able to restore the Registration IDs of all you active users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this method is feasible, but still it may be useful.

- You need to release a new version of your app.
- Whenever an app registered with GCM launches it looks for a registration id and calls for `getRegistrationId()` function. We store that in shared prefs inside our app data.

**Here's some code from the official docs** :

```
private String getRegistrationId(Context context)
{
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");

    if (registrationId.isEmpty())
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }

    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);

    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");

        return "";
    }

    return registrationId;
}
```

- We use a specific key to store the registeration id in shared prefs (here it is **PROPERTY_REG_ID** which is already defined as `public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";`). Each time our app launches our it checks for the presence of this key.
- So what i was suggesting was is to change this shared prefs key for the registration id.

This definitely would not be found in the shared prefs and would ask for a re-registration from the GCM and would call the `registerInBackground()` function.

```
private void registerInBackground()
{
    new AsyncTask()
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            String msg = "";

            try
            {
                if (gcm == null)
                {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }

                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }

            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg)
        {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

After the registration you need to use the new shared prefs key to store the new registration id.

**The drawback of this whole thing is that you can get the registration id of only those who would update the app.**